# Server is configured for Integrated authentication only

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm new to SQL server. I have a very basic idea about it. And on a recent application I needed to use SQL server. But I have to access the db stored on the another computer. So I changed the SQL Server Authentication mode to Mixed Mode, Restarted the instance, opened the 1433 port in the firewall and SQL Configuration Manager and then when I tried to log into the db. I always get the following error.

```
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 58. Login failed for user 'MyNewUser'.
Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Integrated authentication only. [CLIENT: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]
```

I did the confirm that my server is running in the mixed node by running the following command

```
SELECT CASE SERVERPROPERTY('IsIntegratedSecurityOnly')
WHEN 1 THEN 'Windows Authentication Only'
WHEN 0 THEN 'Windows and SQL Server Authentication'
END as [Authentication Mode];
```

And it returned:

```
Authentication Mode
-------------------
Windows and SQL Server Authentication
```

My Connection String:

```
Data Source=xxx.xxx.xx.xxx,1433\(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User Id=MyNewUser;Password=pass@#$word
```

[image]

[image]

Now I'm not quite sure why i can't login. Please help

Comment: have you logon with windows identification checked if that use is there and actove

Comment: Has the SQL Server service been restarted since reconfigured to allow mixed authentication?

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to the right server and instance?

Comment: Yes I did restart the MSSQL service, Browser as well as Agent services. @Dan_Guzman

Comment: Yes, I am trying to connect to the default local instance of the server. I am also including my connection string if that would we be useful. @Charlieface

Comment: `xxx.xxx.xx.xxx,1433\(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` is not valid, and doesn't make any sense: you can't use LocalDB edition over TCP anyway, and LocalDB is never the default instance, so I suspect it's actually connecting to a different instance than the one you think. Have you installed another edition as well as LocalDB

Comment: From the start when I installed the SQL Server. The SSMS had `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` as default server name. So isn't that supposed to be the default instance? That is the server I was trying to connect to. Please take a look at the images attached. @Charlieface

Comment: No, you are connecting to the wrong instance. The conn-string for LocalDB is just `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` and you cannot connect over the network. For SQL Server Express, normally it is a named instance, *not* the default instance (even though that's really what you'd want) so you need `xxx.xxx.xx.xxx\SQLEXPRESS`, or `.\SQLEXPRESS` on the same machine. With a named instance, you need SQL Server Browser service to be running (you do), and you need to check the correct port is open on the firewall

Comment: Ok, i opened the SQLEXPRESS server in ssms but whenever i try to create a new db or new table i getting the following error
`Error: 18461, Severity: 14, State: 1.       Login failed for user 'mypcname\myusername'. Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time. [CLIENT]` and immediately after that `Error: 18461, Severity: 14, State: 1.       Login failed for user 'NT SERVICE\SQLTELEMETRY$SQLEXPRESS'. Reason: Server is in single user mode. Only one administrator can connect at this time. [CLIENT:]` in the logs. @Charlieface

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-sql-server-in-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-ver15 Remove `-m` from the startup parameters

Comment: Alright i did manage to get the Application running over my pc (host PC) but when i run it over the another pc(client PC) in the same network it crashes as i run a query. Now why could that happen? @Charlieface

Comment: I suggest you create a new question for that. But please bear in mind all help you can find online first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci, check things like firewall, connection strings, server remote access and TCP settings, SSL certifcates *before* you post again

Comment: ok thanks @Charlieface